Gem5 --script option doesn't work when using fs.py
When I run gem5 in full system mode with fs.py.    I find that the
.rcS script given to --script doesn't work after system is booted.
I can see 'readfile=/mydata/gem5/configs/boot/hack_back_ckpt.rcS'  line in
config.ini.
But why the command within it is ignored and doesn't work by gem5?
I 've read all that question related to this on gem5 mailing list, but none of
them give a feasible solution.
What's wrong with these?
Thanks,
Yongjie
https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg22353.html
could you shed some lights on it?  debug tricks or something else
